# css property not apply properly [bottom,right]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am create a `div` and in `JavaScript` and after that push it to `Google Map` i attach some `css` properties with that `div` all properties are applied except 1 property that is `bottom` i specify a value of `15px` but it shows `0px`.
Any thoughts how do i apply that.

Demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y5v2Y/10/)

This is how I create `div`

```
var unitControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
unitControlDiv.style.margin = '4px';
unitControlDiv.style.padding = '4px';
unitControlDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'ButtonShadow';
unitControlDiv.style.borderRadius = '10px';
unitControlDiv.style.bottom = '15px';
unitControlDiv.style.right = '10px';
unitControlDiv.className = 'unitContainer';
```

**Update 1**

Following is the css that generated after map load

[image]

i want to change above `bottom` and `right` from `0`,`320px` to `15px`,`10px` respectively

Comment: You have no position defined, so how will that work? `top` doesn't work on static positioned elements

Comment: position is defined automatically. but i want to override the bottom value now. which is always 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT].push(unitControlDiv);
```

This line is basically resetting your bottom css property to '0px' because its positioning the controls to the bottom. To workaround this problem you can use margin bottom.

```
unitControlDiv.style.marginBottom = '50px';
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y5v2Y/11/)

---- Updated ------

So why don't you override it in the css itself...

```
.unitContainer {
    margin:4px;
    padding:4px;
    background-color:ButtonShadow;
    border-radius:10px;
    bottom: 50px !important; /*Changed here*/
}
```

Comment: i know the problem is here so thats why i want to override that with `bottom` not `marginBottom`

Comment: because i don't know about `css` but now it solves bu using `!important`. thanks

Comment: any possibility like that ? `unitControlDiv.style.bottom = '50px !important';`

Comment: yes but its not the best solution though...another way would be create one more div and add the controls div inside that div :D

Comment: i think i should follow the class approach instead of creating new div Thanks :)

Comment: yes...but none of the preset control position work for you? check it out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ControlPosition

Comment: i want this `BOTTOM_RIGHT` but there are also 3 elements `terms`, `copyright`. I am able to hide them but there is `restrictions` according to this https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?csw=1 (8.4b).  So i would like the custom position

Answer (score 0):

> bottom is  a style attribute related to position. you can declare
>   ***position : absolute***  or relative then only the bottom will works
>   otherwise it won't work

```
unitControlDiv.style.marginBottom = '15px';
```

Comment: i want to use `bottom` and `right` so my div will move at the corner of map.